# Casting Problems (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, casting

I've been working on a maze generation assignment, and I am having difficulty with the main segment of my code.

```
        fillNeighbours(neighbours, cell);//this checks to see which  
                                           neighbours are available

        while (neighbours.length > 0) {

            var index:int = (Math.random() * neighbours.length);
            Math.floor(index);
            var ob:Object = neighbours.splice(index, 1);
            trace("ob: " + ob);
            var pnt:Point = (ob as Point);
            trace("pnt: " + pnt);
            generate(pnt);

        }
```

it seems as though casting the object as a point is the problem. since it is not properly transforming the object to the point. When I trace the object, it traces the coordinates of a random point (x, y), but when I trace the point, it traces as null and the error runs: **[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference**. I have been searching for errors over the past 5 days, and am pretty sure it is nothing too petty. If anybody knows what my problem is, I would be willing to buy them food. Pls. Help.

Comment: Your array simply does not contain Point objects.

Comment: But you can do : `var pnt:Point = new Point(ob.x, ob.y); `.

Comment: I changed my code the way that you told me too,
var pnt:Point = new Point(ob.x, ob.y);
I get a trace overflow.
when I trace my variables, ob = (x=10, y=0), and pnt = (x=NaN, y=NaN) 
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`ob as Point` will return `null` if `ob` is not an instance of `Point`. I think you will see that happening in the `trace("pnt"+pnt)` output.

AS3 has another way of casting: `Point(ob)` which will throw a runtime error if `ob` is not a `Point` instance.

Yet another way to check if your `ob` is indeed a `Point`:
`(ob is Point)` which will be `true` only if your `ob` value references a `Point` instance.

I guess @BotMaster was right, saying your array doesn't actually have `Point` instances in it.